# Spring boot kafka set ackOnError in application.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka

Is there a way to set property ackOnError=false using spring boot application.properties file like other listener properties such as:

```
spring.kafka.listener.ack-mode
spring.kafka.listener.ack-count
spring.kafka.listener.ack-time
spring.kafka.listener.poll-timeout
```

?

If it is not possible, how cat I combine: properties from file + java config? I don't want to set all kafka properties in java-config like this:

```
 @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        ......
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
        return props;
    }
```

I just want to override property ackOnError. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not available as a property but you can override Boot's container factory `@Bean` as follows...

```
@Bean
ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
        ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaConsumerFactory) {

    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    configurer.configure(factory, kafkaConsumerFactory);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckOnError(false);
    return factory;
}
```

This will apply all the other boot properties as well.

However, this setting doesn't have much utility unless you also stop the container (e.g. with a `ContainerStoppingErrorHandler`).

This is because the next successful record will have its offset committed anyway, which is beyond the offset of the failed record.

That said, in 2.3, it will be `false` by default.